# Serilog disable the controller name in logs

Tags: c#, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0

I have configured my Serilog in my Asp.NET Core 6 project as the following:

```
public static class SerilogConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        if (builder is null)
            return;

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Async(x => x.Logger((configureLogger) =>
            {
                configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding("@m like '%Service Profiler%' ci");
                configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding("@m like '%Finished calling trace uploader%' ci");
                configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding("@m like '%Uploader to be used%' ci");
                configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding("@m like '%BasicAuthentication was not authenticated%' ci");
                configureLogger.Filter.ByExcluding("@m like '%Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Profiler.Core%' ci");
                configureLogger.Filter.With(new[] { new LogFilterOptions() });
                configureLogger.WriteTo.Async(consoleConfiguration =>
                {
                    consoleConfiguration.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
                        template: "{@l:w4}: {SourceContext}\n" +
                                  "{#if Scope is not null}" +
                                  "\t{#each s in Scope}=> - {s}{#delimit} {#end}\n" +
                                  "{#end}" +
                                  "{@m}\n",
                        theme: TemplateTheme.Code));
                });
            }))
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System.Net.Http.HttpClient", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();

        builder.WebHost.UseSerilog();
    }
}

public class LogFilterOptions : ILogEventFilter
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> ignoredMessages = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
    {
        "Shox.Web.Api.Controllers"
    };

    // Allow the event to be logged if the message template isn't one we ignore
    public bool IsEnabled(LogEvent logEvent) => !ignoredMessages.Contains(logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text);
}
```

Whtat I want to disable the serilog to log the following line at the console:

**info: Shox.Web.Api.Controllers.MediaLibraryController**

Any idea how to do that?
thx

Answer (score 0):

Removing from the console template {SourceContext} solved my problem.